# Understanding the proof that $C_{c}(E)$ is dense in $L^p(E)$ (Royden and Fitzpatrick "Real Analysis" 4th edition page 153)

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Here is the theorem and a hint for the proof before it:

> [image]

But I still do not know a thorough proof for it, proposition 9 proved that simple functions are dense in $L^p(E)$, but then how to proceed that continuous functions are dense in $L^p(E)$ or $L^1([0,1] , m)$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure, that is all what I need, could anyone help me in this please?

Answer (score 1):

In Rudin's Real and Complex he proves that $C_c(\mathbf{R})$ is dense in the space of simple functions.  Density is a transitive relation so we get $C_c(\mathbf{R})$ is dense in $L^p(\mathbf{R})$

Comment: How is it a transitive relation ? do you have a proof for this please?

Comment: are you speaking about this proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1373117/help-understanding-rudins-proof-showing-that-c-cx-is-dense-in-lp-mu?

Comment: actually I have difficulty in understanding notation .... can you give me a proof here depending on I have a proof for that the simple functions are dense in $L^p$?

Comment: @Secretly for the transitivity: suppose you have a metric space X that is dense in a metric space Y and Y is dense in a metric space Z.  we get a little chain of injective maps sending X to Y and Y to Z.  if you compose these maps you will go from X to Z.  These injections will be continuous wrt the metric toplogy and continuous maps send dense sets to dense sets.

Comment: I need it without metric spaces just equations …. by definition of density.

Comment: @Secretly yes I am speaking about the above link.  Try to prove that density is transitive, I think you can do it.  The argument in Rudin is essentially based on that.  The space of Continuous functions of compact support are dense in the space of simple functions with finite measure support and simple functions with finite measure support are dense in $L^p$ Thus $C_c(\mathbf{R})$ is dense in $L^p$